# Is there a possibility to set quota on Google API per credential key?

Tags: api, google-cloud-platform, key, cloud

I would like to plan the cost of Google API usage per credential key.
It however seems possible to set the quota only at the API level, not on key.
Does anyone know of any other solution /alternative?

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible per key, only per service/project. Maybe see check if you can do this per service account?

Answer (score 0):

The quota on the Google Cloud APIs are set to protect the Google Cloud Platform against over usage. Google Cloud doesn't care if it's a service account or another one, it's about a project and a quota per project.

Therefore, it's not possible to achieve what you want. You can imagine to put a layer (Apigee for example) between your app and the Google API to perform that rate limit yourselves, but it's useless because

- the app can reach directly the APIs without the additional layer
- the project quota will be the same, the sum of all the calls can't be higher

---

You have only one exception to that: BigQuery. You can set a ByteBilled volume per day and PER USER! However, you can't have a different quota per user; each user has the same volume authorized.